# Resources for planning a western United States road trip

Tags: usa, online-resources, road-trips

I'm currently planning a road trip through the west of the US.

I'm not a fan of buying books to orientate myself on the subject, I'd rather use information available on the web first. I'm looking for good resources on routes, points of interest and maybe some travel stories.

Comment: Hey TomvB, the Western United States are pretty big and that's a pretty broad question. That's the kind of question that could be answered with an entire *shelf* of books, so it's not really a good fit for our format here, which is more about specific questions and answers you may have. Try starting with Google and ask us any specific questions you come up with, and we'll be standing by to help.

Answer (score 3):

I've been using [My Scenic Drives](http://www.myscenicdrives.com/) to plan my own cross-country roadtrip. They have suggested routes, but they also let you manually enter points of interest and then suggest things around them.

Although My Scenic Drives is still in beta, the folks who make it have been extremely responsive to suggestions, feature requests, and bug reports. :)